# c# Socket Randomly Stops Receiving

Tags: c#, sockets, system.net.sockets

This question may be very hard to answer or perhaps somebody knows a common reason.

I have 1 server, 5 clients;

```
Socket client
Socket listener
```

Every 5000 MS the client checks for a file on the server (Which is Windows 7)via socket, if found the client received the file via socket.

I understand only Windows Server can process more than two asynch file transfers at a time.

My issue is that, randomly the client begins to receive the file. All clients generally work fine. Once in a while, a client will stop receiving the file partthrough and not complete the file transfer and my client program just hangs and never finishes.

I can NOT reproduce this on development environment. I have tested it with half-gig files, 100's of sends and I never get an error.

My question is , is it possible that there is some protocol on Windows 7 that is stopping my file send from the server.

My Receive call back for the client is quite lengthy, but here it is. I do not believe the problem to be within the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My boss is about to have my neck :(

```
 private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.

        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
        state.totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            if (state.flag == 0)
            {
                if (state.totalBytesRead >= 8)
                {
                    // we know we put the msgLen / prefixLen as the first 8 bytes on the stream
                    state.msgLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 0);
                    state.prefixLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 4);
                    state.flag = 1;
                    // good to process the first 2 integer values on the stream
                    //state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 8, bytesRead));

                    int prefixRequestBytes = state.prefixLen;


                    if (prefixRequestBytes > StateObject.BufferSize)
                        prefixRequestBytes = StateObject.BufferSize;

                    state.lastSendByteCount = prefixRequestBytes;
                    state.totalBytesRead = 0;

                    // start re-writing to the begining of the buffer since we saved
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, prefixRequestBytes, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    int bytesToSend = state.lastSendByteCount - bytesRead;
                    state.lastSendByteCount = bytesToSend;
                    // need to receive atleast first 8 bytes to continue
                    // Get the rest of the data.
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, state.totalBytesRead, bytesToSend, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (state.flag == 1)
            {
                // we are expexing to process the prefix
                if (state.totalBytesRead >= state.prefixLen)
                {
                    // we are good to process
                    // Lets always assume that our prefixMsg can fit into our prefixbuffer ( we wont send greater than prefixbuffer)
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, state.prefixLen));
                    string prefixMsg = state.sb.ToString();

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefixMsg))
                    {
                        state.cmd = parseXml("CMD", prefixMsg);
                        state.fName = parseXml("FNAME", prefixMsg);

                        // File requester should never get a del command
                        //if (state.cmd == "DEL")
                        //{
                        //    Console.WriteLine("Processing 'DEL' command..");
                        //    // delete the file

                        //    string filePath = "C:\\" + locationFolder + "\\" + state.fName;

                        //    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                        //    {
                        //        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                        //    }

                        //    Console.WriteLine("Deleted file");
                        //    // receiveDone.Set();
                        //    requestTimer.Start();
                        //    return;
                        //}
                        //else
                        if (state.cmd == "SND")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Processing 'SND' command..");
                            // let it rip
                            if (state.msgLen == 0) // no files
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("No files on server");
                                requestTimer.Start();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }



                    state.receivedPath = importTempFolder + state.fName;

                    // receive the rest of the file
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(state.receivedPath))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Deleting temp file: " + state.receivedPath + " for re-write");
                        System.IO.File.Delete(state.receivedPath);
                    }

                    state.flag++;
                    int msgRequestBytes = state.msgLen;
                    if (msgRequestBytes > StateObject.BufferSize)
                        msgRequestBytes = StateObject.BufferSize;

                    state.lastSendByteCount = msgRequestBytes;
                    state.totalBytesRead = 0;

                    // should be good to process the msg now
                    // start re-writing to the begining of the buffer since we saved
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, msgRequestBytes, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    int bytesToSend = state.lastSendByteCount - bytesRead;
                    state.lastSendByteCount = bytesToSend;
                    // request the rest of the prefix
                    // Get the rest of the data.
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, state.totalBytesRead, bytesToSend, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                    return;
                }
            }

            // we are expecting to process the file
            if (state.flag > 1)
            {
                if (state.totalBytesRead >= state.msgLen)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Writing final {0} bytes to server", bytesRead);

                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(state.receivedPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                    {
                        //BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(state.receivedPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));

                        writer.Write(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        fs.Flush();
                        // writer.Close();

                    }
                    //   GC.Collect();
                    // if temp folder exists, import will exists because its inside it

                    string destFile = importFolder + state.fName;
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(destFile))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Deleting file for re-write in importin: \n" + destFile);
                        System.IO.File.Delete(destFile);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Moving file: \n" + state.receivedPath);
                    System.IO.File.Copy(state.receivedPath, destFile);
                    Console.WriteLine("Deleting file from temp: \n" + state.receivedPath + importTempFolder + state.fName);
                    System.IO.File.Delete(state.receivedPath);



                    if (state.cmd == "SND")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sending 'DEL' command.");
                        SendDeleteResponse(client, state.fName);
                        Console.WriteLine("Finished reading to file: " + state.receivedPath);

                        // receiveDone.Set();
                        requestTimer.Start();
                        return;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Finished reading file");

                    client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    client.Close();

                    // receiveDone.Set();
                    requestTimer.Start();

                }
                else
                {

                    //Console.WriteLine("Reading {0} bytes from server...", bytesRead);
                    // Padd these bytes

                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(state.receivedPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
                    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                    {
                        //BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(state.receivedPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None));

                        writer.Write(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        fs.Flush();
                        //   writer.Close();

                    }
                    //   GC.Collect();

                    // get how many more bytes are left to read
                    int bytesToSend = state.msgLen - bytesRead;

                    if (bytesToSend > StateObject.BufferSize)
                        bytesToSend = StateObject.BufferSize;

                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, bytesToSend, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                    return;


                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            // All the data has arrived;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HERE5 " + e.Message);
        client.Close();
        // receiveDone.Set();
        requestTimer.Start();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem in a development environment, can you try some diagnostics in your production environment?  Running Wireshark or netmon or something similar on your client system would at least let you determine if all the bytes are arriving or not.  Right now the problem could be the server is failing to send all the bytes; the network is failing to deliver all the bytes; the client is failing to receive all the bytes or your code  is failing to receive all the bytes.  Or even the server is sending you an incorrect byte count!

Comment: @clamchoda Have you solved this issue? I have a similar problem, as we're sending data to a server (Windows 7) and then the client is waiting for ACK message, but sometimes (seems random) the ACK is not received. When the server was a Windows XP it worked fine.

Comment: @J.Swietek I did solve this issue. But for me, my client was in the Philippians with very unreliable internet. It was a complete networking drop, loss of connection ect.  There is most likely an un-trapped exception happening either on the client, or the server when this disconnects happens. You need to catch it, and write some sort of functionality to restart or resume the process.